# svn external merge tool

Tags: bash, svn, merge, diff

On Linux, I am using *diffuse* as a diff tool with SVN, which is quite handy in my opinion. However, I would like to use it as a merge tool as well. When using an external merge tool (option (l) while merging) SVN passes five files to it: (i) the unmodified file, (ii) theirs, (iii) mine, (iv) the one to be stored, (v) the current working copy. I don't have a screen that allows me to handle diffuse with five files open at the same time, therefore I would like to know the following:

How can I close just one or two of the open files in diffuse?

or

How can I tell diffuse not to open all of them but just the once I need?

I have tried the following, with out success: The merge-tool is defined in the file `~/.subversion/config` as follows:

```
merge-tool-cmd = diffuse
```

I simply replaced it by

```
merge-tool-cmd = diffuse $2 $3 $4
```

Can anyone help? Thanks and cheers in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Subversion can be fun in this way...

The easiest way is to create a script that executes `diffuse` for you with the right parameters, and then specifying that script in your Subversion configuration.

I did the same thing with `vimdiff`. The Subversion manual [explains](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html) what is involved and gives you an example script in [Python and Windows Batch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools.diff3.ex-1) that you can hack for your own use.

From these two examples, you should be able to put together a short script in any language you prefer.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. From these examples I thought it is easiest to create a bash script that simply contains `diffuse $2 $3 $4` and set it accordingly in the config file: `merge-tool-cmd = /path/to/my_simple_script`. Any idea why diffuse still opens all five arguments?

Comment: No idea why. In your shell script, add `set -xv` above the first line and `set +xv` after the last line. This will display shell scripting debug information, and give you an idea exactly what you're shel script is doing. If you don't display the debugging info, it could be that you're not running the script you think you are.

Comment: You might be over exerting yourself with all of this. According to the [documentation](http://diffuse.sourceforge.net/manual.html#version-control), diffuse already works with version control systems. No info on how it knows about version control (maybe looking for the `.svn` directory?), but you might want to try the diffuse command line with the various version control options, and see if you can get it to work directly with Subversion.